# Why won't my columns with Data Annotations map when using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, data-annotations

I have a class that looks like this:

```
public class Analyst
{
    [Column("Internal_ID")]
    public int ID { get; set; } // if this is named like the column, it works
    [Column("DisplayName")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

This object is being filled like so (this next part is in a class which inherits from DbContext):

```
public List<T> ExecProc<T>(string proc, Dictionary<string, object> params)
{
        var parms = new List<SqlParameter>();
        var sql = new StringBuilder();
        sql.Append(sproc.StoredProcedure);
        sql.Append(" "); //  a space, that's all it is
        foreach (var key in sproc.Parameters.Keys)
        {
            sql.Append(string.Format("{0},", key));
            parms.Add(new SqlParameter(key, sproc.Parameters[key]));
        }
        if (sql[sql.Length - 1] == ',') // removing the trailing ,
        {
            sql.Remove(sql.Length - 1, 1);
        }
        return Database.SqlQuery<T>(sql.ToString(), parms.ToArray()).ToList();
}
```

The returned List contains the correct amount of rows (or objects in this case), but none of the properties are populated with values.  If the proc returns 200 rows, then I get 200 objects in the List, but none of them have any values populated.

I have verified that there is no mismatch between the field names and the values in the [Column("name")] attribute.  If i change the property names to match the field names in the result set, then it works fine, but I cannot seem to get it to work if I try mapping them using the  Data Annotations.  Can anyone please point out what I'm missing here?  I'm certain that it's something simple.

Using: Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate SP1, .Net 4 SP1, EF 4.2.0 (I encountered the same problem with EF 4.3).  This is all done using code only, no mapping files are used for this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As it seems, this is documented behavior. [Database.SqlQuery Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696545%28v=vs.103%29) has no direct connection to DbContext model configuration.

> Creates a raw SQL query that will return elements of the given generic
>   type. **The type can be any type that has properties that match the
>   names of the columns returned from the query**, or can be a simple
>   primitive type.

So, when using this method, you should construct your sql so that result set column names match property names of type used.

Comment: Three years later and this answer helped me out. I have a data model I'm not able to change, but column names that are not in line with our naming conventions.

In the POCO I'm using to deserialize the query, I created a private field for each column in the database, and a public field with the correctly named properties, exposing only a getter method to return the value in the private fields.

This might help somebody out in another three years.

Comment: It helped me out after another 14 months :)